# Accounting for the heading of my position when calculating a new lat/long

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, heading

Suppose that I am in a position where I know my directional heading, latitude and longitude. I throw a ball, and know that it lands X meters in front of me and Y meters to my left.

From here, I want to calculate the ball's landing site in latitude/longitude. I know I can calculate a vector of where the ball lands relative to me, but I'm unsure of how to also account for the directional heading of my position.

I'm not a GIS person by any means, and am trying to write a Python script that does something similar.

Comment: Look up haversine formula (there are many methods and libraries for python) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points

Comment: The problem is a partial differential equation, with the formal name of the [Direct Geodetic Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems), so it's not really something to code on your own. Then again, you're not throwing that ball more than 200 meters, so it really doesn't matter which blade of grass it hits.  But if you really want accuracy, you should be using a verified code library.

Comment: @Vince I think I understand what problem your linked article describes, and agree that I'll need to use a library. However, let me clarify my initial question: How do I account for both my own directional heading, and the direction of the second point relative to me? Is it as simple as knowing my direction in radians, and adding the radians of the offset second point?

Comment: Use something like pyproj to convert your lat/long to Cartesian coordinates.  You know the distance and direction so that is a polar coordinate from your pseudo origin.  Convert to the polar back to Cartesian, add or subtract from your Cartesian location.

Comment: The Direct problem solves point2 from point1, bearing, and distance. You can compute then actual bearing and distance from basic trig (SOH-CAH-TOA) from the direction you were facing, the adjacent of your throw, and the opposite of the leftward drift.  If you obtained hyperaccurate locations of both your center of axis and the ball, then you'd use the Inverse (Reverse) Problem to solve for bearing, distance, and backangle between the two points.  But this really only matters when the distances are kilometers, not meters.